# new XAMPP giving me million errors

Tags: php, xampp

I used to have old version of Portable Xampp, all my codes where running correctly.

Today I installed the latest version - portable (then I tried install).

The pages is giving a lot of errors and the code is not running

something like this:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant server_name - assumed 'server_name' in D:\xampp\htdocs\aviaeng\settings.php on line 14

Notice: Use of undefined constant db_name - assumed 'db_name' in D:\xampp\htdocs\aviaeng\settings.php on line 15

Notice: Use of undefined constant username - assumed 'username' in D:\xampp\htdocs\aviaeng\settings.php on line 16

Notice: Use of undefined constant password - assumed 'password' in D:\xampp\htdocs\aviaeng\settings.php on line 17

Notice: Use of undefined constant contact_email - assumed 'contact_email' in D:\xampp\htdocs\aviaeng\settings.php on line 18
```

and on the browser I have

```
<? echo $lang[website_name] ?>
```

which means the PHP is not being read by Xampp.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Please show us your code! Also make sure: 1. php installed file ends with `*.php` and you call the file over the server (Which has to be turned on!) `localhost/index.php`

Comment: it seems you are running code written in PHP 3. It's normal you get 1 billion of errors

Comment: Which was your old PHP version... ? It seems you're still using short open tag.

Comment: @Begueradj 
I start realizing this. I replaced <? with <?PHP and the code is being interpreted.

Comment: You are using terrible coding... You must declare your attributes as a string, otherwise it is considered a constant.

<? echo $lang[website_name] ?>

Should be
<?php echo $lang['website_name']; ?>

Your production server likely suppresses the warnings and errors.

Comment: @Saad you will need to rewrite your code with the syntax of the new version you installed. But do not be scared: even if your program is huge, you can debug it by patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your code is not compatible syntaxically speaking with the new PHP version you installed.

With patience, you can debug your code to adapt its syntax to your new PHP version. Courage :)

Comment: So the older PHP version can understand code with higher flexibility than the newer :(

Comment: @Saad One of the reasons you must adapt your code to your new PHP version is SECURITY. Especially if you are going to deploy it on internet. I saw a conference on Youtube of Rasmus Lerdorf where he said that using PHP 3 is a very bad thing. It will be useful for you to adapt it to the new version on all the sides.

Comment: Thanks a lot .

I will do this .